# GIT conflict in Storyboard and results error as main.storyboard not found

Tags: ios, xcode, git, storyboard, file-not-found

I've tried taking pull from GIT and some conflicts occurred on my Storyboard file.
I have resolved all conflicts from a different computer (windows computer) and then replaced new Main.storyboard file with old file (on Mac).

Now, when i run my project an error occur that says *main.storyboard not found*.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you (downvoter) please give me the reason for down-vote?
I guess StackOverflow is a site where you post your queries, no matters either it's a simple query or difficult one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to add the storyboard to the project.
Select the file in project navigator, then check if your build target in the options panel on the right is checked.

Comment: No the file is there but i guess its reference is somehow deleted.
I replaced the old main.storyboard file from the new merged main.storyboard file.

Comment: That's what I'n talking about. When you can see the file in the navigator, that does not mean it has been added to your build target. Open the properties on panel on the right and look for your target - it should be checked